Schedule batch to run everyday 2PM with batch size of 10 in anonymous block
In production, I have the batch class scheduled thru 'Schedule Apex' button in the UI and recently started failing because of governance limit. To test with lower batch size 10 (below), I could run the batch successfully.
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new BatchFinanceInfoHistory(), 10);
Now, I wanted to schedule the class with batch size as 10 in production instead of running manually the above step in anonymous block. Do we have any immediate fix to run in anonymous block without creating Schedulable class i.e. without any production deployment? If no, how should the new Schedulable class look?
Thanks in advance.

You will need to write a Schedulable class, see the documentation.

Salesforce provides the System.scheduleBatch function, but this only allows a single scheduling. To make a persistent scheduled job, you need to deploy a Schedulable class.
You can make a reusable Schedulable class using the following code:
public class ScheduleSObjectBatch implements Schedulable {
    Database.Batchable<sobject> batchToExecute;
    Integer size;
    public ScheduleSObjectBatch(Database.Batchable<sobject> batch, Integer scopeSize) {
        batchToExecute = batch;
        size = scopeSize;
    }
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(batchToExecute, size);
    }
}

This is intended to be called from Execute Anonymous:
System.schedule(
  JOB_NAME, 
  CRON_STRING, 
  new ScheduleSObjectBatch(
    new BatchYouWantToSchedule(),
    SCOPE_SIZE
  )
);

This should work with all Database.QueryLocator- or List<sObject>-based batchable classes.

I thought we can have a code that can be run in anonymous block without any deployment but this helps. Thanks

@MaheshRaghuraman Unless you already had a scheduler built, you need a deployment. That's why I build tools like these, to make it easier to do things in production without deployments.
